# Why the variable defined in outer section is not available in inner sector?

Tags: clojure

I have the following code, in the second line I defined file-fields-in-keyword, but it's only availabe in line 3, ine line 10 and 24, it prints nil. But why line 10,24 see nil while line 3 could see the non-nil value? I expect they are the same

```
(defn load-file-to-database [file-name file-id constraints-map auto-creation-config delimiter]
  (let [file-fields-in-keyword (get-file-header-as-key-word file-name)]
    (println file-fields-in-keyword)
    (with-open [rdr (io/reader file-name)]
      (doseq [chunk (partition-all 10000  (map-indexed
                                           (fn [index line] (str file-id delimiter (inc index) delimiter line))
                                           (line-seq rdr)
                                           ))]
        (println (count chunk))
        (println file-fields-in-keyword)   ;; it prints nil
        (println (first chunk))
        (let [rows (map #(clojure.string/split %  #",") chunk)
              rows-map (map #(zipmap file-fields-in-keyword %) rows)
              rows-after-validation (map #(process-row % constraints-map auto-creation-config) rows-map)
              valid-records (valid-lines rows-after-validation)
              invalid-records (invalid-lines rows-after-validation)
              ]

          (println (count valid-records))
          (println (count invalid-records))
          (println (first valid-records))
          (println (first invalid-records))
          (println "xxx")
          (println file-fields-in-keyword) ;; it prints nil
          (apply (partial j/insert! postgres-db  'test_clojure file-fields-in-keyword) valid-records)
          )))
    )
  )

(defn get-file-header-as-key-word [file-name]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader file-name)]
    (println (map keyword (str/split (str row_number "," "file_id" "," (first (line-seq rdr))) #",")))
    ))


(load-file-to-database file-name 100 constraints-map auto-creation-config ",")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, all three values should be the same.

The value returned from the function `get-file-header-as-key-word` is always `nil` since `println` always returns that value, so all three calls to `println` should print `nil` as the value for `file-fields-in-keyword`.

To get a non-`nil` value from the `get-file-header-as-key-word` function you need to remove the call to `println`. That should result in all output from the `println` in `load-file-to-database` to be the same non-`nil` value.